# Qlikview Wildcard Set Analysis

Tags: qlikview

I am struggling with an expression-based set analysis that includes wildcard search. The goal is to sum cost from purchase order lines while excluding those that have Inventory IDs matching a list (Exclusion Inventory ID). The issue is that the Exclusion IDs are shorter and need to be wild card matched. The expression I have so far is:

```
Sum({$<InventoryID-={$(='*'&ExclusionInventoryID&'*')}>}Cost)
```

However, this is returning nulls all the way down. Is there something wrong with the expression or is what I'm trying to do even possible? Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Sum({$<InventoryID-={'*$(=ExclusionInventoryID)*'}>}Cost)`

but it would be best to assign the field `ExclusionInventoryID` to a variable and then `Sum({$<InventoryID-={'*$(vExclusionInventoryID)*'}>}Cost)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Why do you recommend to assign the field to a variable?